# Make 'To' field only show one recipient

Tags: php, html, forms, email

This is the PHP code I am using upon clicking 'Submit' button at the form.

Currently, when user inputs the email addresses, the message will be sent to those people. Upon checking my email when I was testing, I noticed that at the 'To:' field, it shows all the recipients.

I would like to hide the rest of the recipients' emails. How do I do this?

```
<?php   
    // request variables like beneath // important 
    // $name=$_REQUEST["name"];   
    // multiple recipients 
    $to = $_REQUEST['email1'] . ', '; // note the comma 
    $to .= $_REQUEST['email2'];   
    // subject 
    $subject = 'Movie World: Stay Tuned!';

    $message = '
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Movie World</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>Movie World you would not wanna miss!</p>
            </body>
        </html>
    ';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set 
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers 
    $headers .= 'From: Movie World <movie@movieworld.com>'; 

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Success! Thank you for your enquiry.");
    <!--
        window.location = "form.html"
    //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an additional header for BCC, Blind Carbon Copy

`$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $_REQUEST['email2'] . "\r\n";`

Comment: what if I have more than two emails? let's say $_REQUEST['email3'] and $_REQUEST['email4'] ?

Comment: Simply do what you were trying to do with the To field. `$headers .= "Bcc: ".$_REQUEST['email2']."; ".$_REQUEST['email3']."\r\n";`

Comment: Tried your method. I don't want a Bcc actually, it's more like sending an email individually to all the recipients. Their own respective email addresses will be shown at the 'To:' field. Each recipient can only view their email address on the 'To:' field.

Comment: You really need to be more specific in your questions, and also accept the answers given to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a `bcc` then you need to use a `foreach` or similar.

Collect an array of email addresses using
`<input type="text" name="address[]" />`

then loop through them:

```
foreach($_POST['address'] as $email) :
    $to = null;
    $to = $email;
    // validate the email
    // set up the headers
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
endforeach;
```

might be worth looking at a [proper mail library](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected) for anything more advanced.

And be careful as this kind of form can be a goldmine to spammers unless you control the input properly by limiting the amount of emails, proper sanitization etc.

Comment: Tried but can't seem to work, probably the placement. Could you assist me a little bit more? 

This is part of my form.

<tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="email[]" id="email1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email[]" id="email2" />
    </td>
  </tr>